# Why the below code is not printing the value 10?

Tags: c, pointers

Why the below code is not printing the value 10? rather it crashes..

```
void foobar(int *a) 
{   
    int *c;
    c = *a;

    printf("%d\n", *c);
}

int main(void)
{   
    int *b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 10;
    foobar(&b);
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858) Compile with warnings enabled and **pay attention to warnings.** In particular, look for "incompatible types in assignment" or similar. Also, **think about** what the code does (what the meaning of each of the declarations and the `&` operator is, etc.)

Comment: what you want to archive by `c = *a;`?

Comment: Crash probably caused by pointers being larger than an `int`, see igoris answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try making these small changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void foobar(int *a) {
  printf("%d\n", *a); /* what was C about? */
}

int main(void) {
  int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *b = 10;
  foobar(b); /* pass the pointer b, not the address of the pointer b. */
  free(b);
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks, I was hasty. I fixed it.

Comment: Although this surely is way to go to print a `10`. It somehow does **not** answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should include `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`

Second, your function declaration is incorrect. It should be

```
void foobar(int **a)
```

instead of

```
void foobar(int *a)
```

Because you are passing pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The code misses to include `<stdlib.h>` and most likley runs on 64 bit.

To fix it do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for prototype of malloc() */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for prototype of printf() */

void foobar(int ** a)  /* Fixed wrong type. */
{   
  int * c = *a;

  printf("%d\n", *c);
}

int main(void)
{    
  int * b = malloc(sizeof(*b)); /* Removed unnecessary and dangerous cast. */
  if (NULL != b) /* Added error checking. */
  {
    *b = 10;

    foobar(&b);
  }

  free(b); /* Added clean up. */

  return 0; /* Added return (unnecessary from C99 on). */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> //--------> ERROR 3: INCLUDE STDLIB FOR MALLOC() FUNCTION

 void foobar(int *a)
{
    int *c;
    c = *a; //--------->ERROR 2 : C POINTS TO THE CONTENTS OF A POINTER

    printf("%d\n", *c);
}

 // SOLUTION 1 : KEEP FUNCTION PROTOTYPE SAME AND PASS B TO FOOBAR AND MAKE C POINT TO    A.
 // SOLUTION 2 : CHANGE FOOBAR'S PROTOTYPE TO FOOBAR(INT**A).

 int main(void)
{
     int *b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
     *b = 10;
     foobar(b); //-------->ERROR 1 : PASSING THE ADDRESS OD A POINTER VARIABLE
```

### }

solution 1 :foobar(b); in main and c=a;

solution 2 :foobar(int **a);

Answer (score 0):

Crashed due to wrong argument type in void foobar(int *a)

It should have been void foobar(int **a)

Though for requirement just correct foobar(&b) => foobar(b)

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about types for a minute.

Given the declaration

```
T *p;
```

then the following are all true:

```
Expression         Type        Value
----------         ----        -----
         p         T *         Address of the thing p points to
        *p         T           Value of the thing p points to
        &p         T **        Address of the variable p
```

In `main`, you declare `b` as `int *`.  In `foobar`, you declare both `a` and `c` as type `int *`.

In the call to `foobar`, you're using the expression `&b`, which has type `int **`; this doesn't match up with the type of `a` (and should have resulted in a diagnostic from the compiler).  What you're doing is passing the address of the *variable* `b` to `foobar`, which is not what you want; you want to pass the value contained in `b`, which is the address of the memory you grabbed from the `malloc` call.  So if you change your call to `foobar` to read

```
foobar(b);
```

the code should work as you expect.

A picture might help a bit.  All of the addresses are pulled out of thin air, and are not meant to represent any real-world platform; assume big-endian representation as well:

```
Item        Address        0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----        -------        ----  ----  ----  ----
heap memory 0x00800000     0x00  0x00  0x00  0x0a
   b        0xfff78000     0x00  0x80  0x00  0x00
   a        0xfff781c0     0x00  0x80  0x00  0x00
   c        0xfff781c4     0x00  0x80  0x00  0x00
```

The call to `malloc` allocates 4 bytes starting at address 0x008000000; after the assignment `*b = 10`, those four bytes contain the value 0x0000000a.

`b`, `a`, and `c` are all variables with `auto` extent; all three contain the heap memory address as their value.  The *expressions* `*b`, `*a`, and `*c` should all evaluate to whatever's being stored at address 0x008000000; that is, the integer value `10`.  `&b` evaluates to the address of `b`, or 0xfff78000.

As others have mentioned, don't cast the result of `malloc`.  It's not required (at least, not in C as of the 1989 standard; C++ and earlier versions of C are different stories), and under the 1989 standard it can suppress a useful diagnostic if you forgot to `#include` stdio.h or otherwise don't have a declaration for `malloc` in scope.  The general form for a `malloc` call is

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * num_elements );
```

so in your case it would read

```
int *b = malloc( sizeof *b );
```

Note that you should always clean up after yourself, even for toy programs like this, so you'll want to add

```
free( b );
```

before you exit your program.